# Tickera WordPress Plugin, getting a PayPal IPN error e-mail

Tags: wordpress, paypal

I purchased the Tickera wordpress plugin from Tickera.com. I have repeatedly requested support from them, but they don't respond.

I installed this plugin on a client's website to sell tickets for an event. The plugin works. The visitor buys the ticket via paypal and then they are sent an e-mail with a PDF attachment of the ticket which can be scanned at the event.

The problem is that with each transaction, my client gets an e-mail from PayPal with this statement:
Please check your server that handles PayPal Instant Payment Notifications (IPN). IPNs sent to the following URL(s) are failing: 
and then it has my client's URL with the folder where the WordPress lives and then ?ipn=paypal.

Do I need to open a IPN account on PayPal to stop the error e-mail? I have been afraid to do this, in case it screws up the function of the plugin. It is working now.

Does anyone have experience with this?

-w

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the plugin must be setting the IPN URL using the NotifyURL parameter of API requests, or just the notify parameter in a standard HTML button/form.  That would override anything you set up in your PayPal profile anyway.

It sounds like there must be some sort of a problem with the IPN script itself that is causing it to send a failure code of some sort back to PayPal's IPN server.  You should be able to check your web server logs for the times that URL is getting hit and see the result there so you can look at the error and resolve it.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I will check the error logs. The strange thing is that it is working. So the IPN info coming back from PayPal is doing what it needs to.

Comment: I check the logs and the address on the paypal e-mail is generating a 404.

Comment: Ok, well you've got something funny going on then, because 404 would be not found, but if the stuff that IPN would be doing is indeed happening, then that wouldn't fit.  There are definitely situations where people have a script that nearly completes, so all of the tasks actually do get done and it looks like it all worked, but then something at the very end of the IPN script caused a failure that sends a 500 back to PayPal.  Again, though, 404 would be something different, so you must have 2 URL's getting hit somehow..??

Answer (score 0):

I would be very reluctant using this plugin - see Facebook for more than enough reasons. As to not try to say too much, I will just say "client side only validation" and "tickera == name your own price ticket system".  What made this bug even worse is that it could be triggered accidentally by merely using normal browser behavior and so a kid with no knowledge of Javascript or the sort could still easily add 4 tickets, proceed to payment, click back in the browser and again proceed and get 4 tickets for the price of 1... Someone with a bit more knowledge and malicious intent could mess with a client side value array and set prices to $0.01/ea if they wished...  I was consulting for someone in an attempt to clean up the mess from using this plugin and quickly discovered Tickera to be less than helpful on the support front... Best I can tell, the client-only-validation "bug" (horrible design) is still in play.. When notified of the bug, they were pretty much like "Oh, no biggie - just review all sales and cancel/refund/etc manually" - an unacceptable solution for medium/large events and just bad business for an event of any size... There are some serious security concerns with this plugin and their lack of response or support is just the icing on the cake... Beware.

Comment: One day the plugin just stopped working. The public was getting to PayPal to purchase their ticket and the info wasn't getting back to the plugin. I put yet another request for support which went unanswered. I then switched the client to TicketLeap. Thanks for your response.